# How to align the versioned code by git with unversioned code?

Tags: git, version-control, versioning, git-flow

In my company we don't use a version control system.
Simply, we have a network folder **G** that contains the last stable version of code.

The developers copy that code to their local machine **L** for their projects, change files and copy them back from **L** to **G**.

An elect developer compiles the updated source in **G** and releases a new version of the application.

Now we try to start to use Git to manage sources. Me (D1) and an other developer (D2) use Git and it works very well! **But** at the same time, other developers D3, D4, D5, D6 continue to use the old method copying the code from and to the network directory.

At this moment, how can I align the code base in **G** with the one in Git, until all developers switch over to use Git?

We use git-flow, and my idea is to align the `master` branch from/to the G network folder ... but:

- When? On each release by D3-D5 developers or can I do it less frequently?
- By whom? Must update be done by the developer who made the changes?
- How? Merging files (thereby affecting the modification date) or replacing files when it is possible?

Do you have others suggestions to manage this (hopefully) temporary situation?

Answer (score 1):

Align git and unversioned code is really has not very efficient way to use. If the other developers D3, D4, D5, D6 have even little knowledge about git, below method can be used:

1. Create the other git repo repo1 for D3~D6. They work on `dev` branch on repo1 (`git checkout -b dev` ) and you two (D1, D2) work on `master` branch on your repo. **Note:** your repo should not have the branch name dev.
2. For D3~D6, they can use `git add filename` to add a file, `git commit -am 'message'` to commit changes and use `git push` to push changes to remote repo1.
3. D1 and D2 align the code:

   `git remote add other <URL for other repo>
   git pull other
   git checkout dev
   git checkout master
   git merge dev
   git push origin master
   git push other master:dev`
4. After you changed the code both for your repo and repo1, D3~D6 should update their code base by `git pull`.

For the questions:

When, it dependent on your project process. And if both of you make big changes, you should align.
Who and How is in the method above.